# Why can I access the variable in the functional interface

Tags: java, anonymous-class, functional-interface

I have a question about functional interfaces in Java. Im still new to the whole concept. So I was testing out creating an an anonymous inner class in IntelliJ. I created an interface called Age and tried to create an anonymous inner class using the Age interface(not sure how I would phrase that, I believe the class implements Age). I accessed the variable x inside of the anonymous inner class no problem. Then I tried to do the same with the functional interface and it says the variable doesn't exist. I'm confused as to why I am unable to access the variable 'x' in the functional interface however I can access it in the anonymous inner class. Could someone please explain, thanks!

```
public class AnonymousInnerClassDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Age oj1 = new Age() {
            @Override
            public void getAge() {
                // printing  age
                System.out.print("Age is "+ x);
            }
        };
        oj1.getAge();

        Age age = () -> System.out.print("Age is 24" + x);
    }

    interface Age {
        int x = 21;
        void getAge();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note `x` is implicitly `static` and `final`.

Comment: As for the question, it could be the same reason you can't refer to the lambda expression with `this`. In an anonymous class `this` refers to the instance of the anonymous class, whereas in a lambda expression `this` refers to the instance of the class the lambda expression is created in. In other words, it's like lambda expressions don't have an identity from within.

Comment: Ohhhh ok that makes sense. So x in the Age anonymous class could be referring to an instance of the interface Age. However, for the functional interface 'x' refers to the 'AnonymousInnerClassDemo' class and there is no  variable x within that class. If that is the case then it makes sense can anyone confirm this?